# Parent and children pagination in django

Tags: django, pagination

In Django I have a category model and post model. Each category has a lot of posts so now I want to render the tag with all its post and make it paginated. How do I add pagination in my `TagDetailView()`.

Code here :

```py
class TagDetailView(DetailView, MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = Tags
    template_name = 'one_tag.html'
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        object_list = Posts.objects.filter(tag_belongs=self.get_object()).order_by('-id')
        context = super(TagDetailView, self).get_context_data(object_list=object_list, **kwargs)
        return context
```

So in each tag to be viewed i wanna all its posts but with pagination feature